# How to perform an exact test of Chi-square for a single-dimension data in R?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, exact-test

I have a data frame like this:

```
> fr.t.r
     A     B    C    D    E
Freq 13    3    0    0    0
```

and I would like to do a Chi-square test to find out if the difference among the 5 groups is significant. So I did this:

```
> chisq.test(fr.t.r)
        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  fr.t.r
X-squared = 39.625, df = 4, p-value = 5.174e-08

Warning message:
In chisq.test(fr.t.r) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Then I thought the number of observations is small, so I need to do an exact test. But fisher.test can only be done on contingency tables. So how should I do it as what can be done in SPSS?

Comment: There is a multinomial exact test that is used in situations where you might use a chi-square goodness-of-fit test.  I'm not sure how valuable the result would be with 60% of the counts being zero, and the sum of the counts being 16.

Comment: Thank you. I did multinomial.test and R gave a P value which equals to 0. Is it possible that the probability of a hypothesis is 0? If not, how to present the result? P<0.001?

Comment: You can get the function to report the p value with 4 decimal places, so you can report a 0 result as p < 0.0001.  Compare `Count=c(5,5,5,1,0); Prob=rep(1/5,5); library(EMT); multinomial.test(Count,Prob)` with `Count=c(5,5,5,0,0)`.  An alternative function is `if(!require(XNomial)){install.packages("XNomial")}; Count=c(13,3,0,0,0); Prob=rep(1/5,5); library(XNomial); xmulti(Count,Prob)`